# Interpretation variance ratio test for time series data and log(data)

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, heteroscedasticity

In [matlab example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/vratiotest.html), The hypothesis is: the series is a random walk.

The following is vratiotest results for DataTable.SP and log(DataTable.SP)

```
>> flag = logical([1 1 1 0 0 0]);
>> [h,pValue,stat,cValue,ratio] = vratiotest(DataTable.SP,'period',q,'IID',flag); 
h =

     0     0     1     0     0     0

pValue =

    0.6059    0.1350    0.0146    0.7359    0.3284    0.0993

stat =

    0.5160   -1.4946   -2.4420    0.3373   -0.9774   -1.6481

cValue =

    1.9600    1.9600    1.9600    1.9600    1.9600    1.9600

ratio =

    1.0100    0.9458    0.8600    1.0100    0.9458    0.8600

>> [h,pValue,stat,cValue,ratio] = vratiotest(log(DataTable.SP),'period',q,'IID',flag); 

h =

     0     0     1     0     0     0

pValue =

    0.5670    0.3307    0.0309    0.7004    0.5079    0.1303

stat =

    0.5724   -0.9727   -2.1579    0.3847   -0.6621   -1.5128

cValue =

    1.9600    1.9600    1.9600    1.9600    1.9600    1.9600

ratio =

    1.0111    0.9647    0.8763    1.0111    0.9647    0.8763
```

- What does flag mean? why does it has only 2 values: 1 or 0 ?
- Why do they use log(DataTable.SP) to check whether DataTable.SP is a
  random walk instead of DataTable.SP ?